# Reading JSON sent using websocket with JQuery

Tags: jquery, json, websocket

I am trying to push some information to the client through a JSON object and a websocket connection. The JSON object is correctly sent because I have checked it with a JSON web application and was fine.

Once recevied, this is the jquery-client code;

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var WEBSOCKET_ROUTE = "/ws";

    if(window.location.protocol == "http:"){
        //localhost
        var ws = new WebSocket("ws://" + window.location.host + WEBSOCKET_ROUTE);
        }
    else if(window.location.protocol == "https:"){
        //Dataplicity
        var ws = new WebSocket("wss://" + window.location.host + WEBSOCKET_ROUTE);
        }

    ws.onopen = function(evt) {
        $("#ws-status").html("Connected");
        };

    ws.onmessage = function(evt) {
    var json = JSON.parse(evt.data);
    $("#dia").html(json);
        };

    ws.onclose = function(evt) {
        $("#ws-status").html("Disconnected");
        };

$("#manual_on").click(function(x){
            var msg = {
    type: 'manual',
        text: $('#manual_on').val(),
    };
     ws.send(JSON.stringify(msg));
    $('#manual_on').val()= "";
        });

$("#manual_off").click(function(x){
         var msg = {
    type: 'manual',
        text: $('#manual_off').val(),
    };
     ws.send(JSON.stringify(msg));
    $('#manual_off').val() = "";
        });

$("#apertura").click(function(x){
         var msg = {
    type: 'programacion',
        hora: $('#hora').val(),
    minutos: $('#minutos').val(),
    tiempo: $('#tiempo').val(),
    lunes: $('#lu').prop('checked'),
    martes: $('#ma').prop('checked'),
    miercoles: $('#mi').prop('checked'),
    jueves: $('#ju').prop('checked'),
    viernes:$('#vi').prop('checked'),
    sabado: $('#sa').prop('checked'),
    domingo: $('#do').prop('checked'),
    };
     ws.send(JSON.stringify(msg));
        });
  });
```

This is also the server-side python/tornado code:

```
    #! /usr/bin/python

import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.websocket
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
from tornado.ioloop import PeriodicCallback
import socket
import os.path
import json
import time

#Tornado Folder Paths
settings = dict(
    template_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "templates"),
    static_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "static")
    )


class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    print "[HTTP](MainHandler) User Connected."
    self.render("index.html")

class WSHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def open(self):
    self.callback = PeriodicCallback(self.send_msg, 120)
        self.callback.start()
        print 'new connection'

    def on_message(self, message):      
    data = json.loads(message)

    if data['type'] == 'programacion':

        hora=int(data['hora'])
        minuto=int(data['minutos'])
        tiempo=int(data['tiempo'])
        l=int(data['lunes'])
        m=int(data['martes'])
        x=int(data['miercoles'])
        j=int(data['jueves'])
        v=int(data['viernes'])
        s=int(data['sabado'])
        d=int(data['domingo'])
        global daylist
            daylist = []
            n=-1
            for i in (l, m, x, j, v, s, d):
             n=n+1
             if i==1:
                  daylist.append(n)
        print(time.time())

    elif data['type'] == 'manual': 
          print('manual')



    def on_close(self):
        print 'connection closed'

    def send_msg(self):
      timing=time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
      timing2={'tiempo':timing}
      print json.dumps(timing2)
      self.write_message(json.dumps(timing2))

#sched.add_cron_job(job_function, month='6-8,11-12', day='3rd fri', hour='0-3')


application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r'/', MainHandler),
    (r'/ws', WSHandler),
   ], **settings)



if __name__ == "__main__":

    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
    http_server.listen(8888)
    myIP = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
    print '*** Websocket Server Started at %s***' % myIP
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Everything works well except when I try to read the JSON in the client-side and put it in the html. I have been looking on this forum and on the internet but did not find anything. Could you give me a hand?

Thanks.

Comment: how are you instantiation your ws object? Post full code.

Comment: ok, I have post the whole code in both server and client sides.

Comment: is the onmessage event being triggered at all? can you put a console.log('trigger') inside the event and see if it's triggered at all?

Comment: This what I get in CONSOLE LOG: message { target: WebSocket, isTrusted: true, data: "{"tiempo": "15:17:44"}", origin: "ws://localhost:8888", lastEventId: "", eventPhase: 0, bubbles: false, cancelable: false, defaultPrevented: false, timeStamp: 1481465864812088, originalTarget: WebSocket }  ws-client.js:20:6

Comment: It's working then and it's no problem. Change $("#dia").html(json); to $("#dia").text(json); and you should be fine.

Comment: Yes, but I had to write it this way $("#dia").text(json.tiempo) to aim the value I wanted from the JSON object, even if there's just one. Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there was nothing wrong with the implementation, just on how the response was written in the html

```
$("#dia").text(json.tiempo)
```